# How to transfer skin weights from one bone to another via python

Tags: python, maya, mel

I want to transfer the skin weights from one bone to another. Can anyone tell be how I might do so?

This code assumes you're only selecting two bones at a time

```
import pymel.core as pm

oldjnt = pm.ls("*_oldJnt", sl=True, type='joint')[0]
newjnt = pm.ls("*_newJnt", sl=True, type='joint')[0]

pm.skinCluster( "skinCluster1", e=True, selectInfluenceVerts=oldjnt,)
pm.skinPercent(tmw=oldjnt, tmw=newjnt, "skinCluster1")
```

I'm not sure how to get the transformMoveWeights (tmw) to apply from one bone to another the way it does in Mel.

Here's the Mel code:

```
skinCluster -e -selectInfluenceVerts Jnt_oldJnt skinCluster1;
skinPercent -tmw Jnt_oldJnt -tmw Jnt_newJnt skinCluster1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you almost had it, but just some syntax errors with the command. I know your code is only trying to transfer from one joint, but this example will loop through all joints that match the right naming. As long as the oldJnt names match properly with the newJnt, it should transfer weights from the right one:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Select all vertexes from your mesh.
cmds.select("pSphere1.vtx[*]")

# We use sorted so that if the objects are names properly, the order of the objects should match indexes.
old_objs = sorted(cmds.ls("*_oldJnt")) # Get a list of all of your old joints.
new_objs = sorted(cmds.ls("*_newJnt")) # Get a list of all of your new joints.

# Use zip to loop through both old and new joints.
for old_jnt, new_jnt in zip(old_objs, new_objs):
    cmds.skinPercent("skinCluster1", tmw=[old_jnt, new_jnt]) # Transfer weights from the old joint to the new one.

# Clear vertex selection.
cmds.select(clear=True)
```

I'm using `cmds` here but you can also switch it to `pymel` if you like.

The docs mention that it will only transfer weights from selected vertexes, so in this example I simply select all vertexes.

This has been tested with a sphere and 2 old joints to 2 new joints.

Comment: Thanks! This was great.

I used the selection method because the old joint and the new joints didn't necessarily have a 1-to-1 naming convention.